# How to access java class method from different maven project using class loader

Tags: java

trying to access a java class method from different maven project using class loader. able to load and retrieve all the methods available in the respective class. but, it's not invoking the method.

my code snippet.

```
File file = new File("/sr/main/java/");
     try {
        URL url = file.toURI().toURL();
        URL[] urls = new URL[]{url};
        Object obj = null;
        
        ClassLoader cl = new URLClassLoader(urls);
        Class<?> cls = cl.loadClass("userDefineKeywords");
        
        obj = cls.getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance();
        
        Object[] args1 = null;
        
        Method[] methods =cls.getDeclaredMethods();

        for(int i=0; i<methods.length;i++) {
            if(methods[i].getName().contentEquals("printMsg")) {
                //obj =methods[i].getDeclaringClass();
                methods[i].invoke(obj, args1);
                System.out.println(methods[i].isAccessible());
            }   
        }
    } catch (MalformedURLException | ClassNotFoundException | IllegalArgumentException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Calling class:

```
public class userDefineKeywords { 
public void printMsg() {
    System.out.println("the invoking class");
}
```

}

something making obj to null here:

```
public Object invoke(Object obj, Object[] args)
    throws IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException
{
    // We can't inflate methods belonging to vm-anonymous classes because
    // that kind of class can't be referred to by name, hence can't be
    // found from the generated bytecode.
    if (++numInvocations > ReflectionFactory.inflationThreshold()
            && !ReflectUtil.isVMAnonymousClass(method.getDeclaringClass())) {
        MethodAccessorImpl acc = (MethodAccessorImpl)
            new MethodAccessorGenerator().
                generateMethod(method.getDeclaringClass(),
                               method.getName(),
                               method.getParameterTypes(),
                               method.getReturnType(),
                               method.getExceptionTypes(),
                               method.getModifiers());
        parent.setDelegate(acc);
    }

    return invoke0(method, obj, args);
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: *it's not invoking the method.* - what exactly it does? what is your expected behaviour? any debugging details?

Comment: it's does nothing, no error. expected behavior, just execute the method.

Comment: Have you done any debugging to find out what it IS finding? The File definition looks like it has a typo and the class name doesn't adhere to Java naming conventions.  But I would expect those to produce exceptions and you report there are none.  Can you add the relevant portion of the class you are trying to invoke?

Comment: debug the code and get a close look inside the loop, specially:  methods[i].getName().contentEquals("printMsg")

Comment: @vsfDawg i have added the calling class in the body

Comment: @icrovett have debug the code and added the method where obj value is getting turn to null

Comment: Two things i found strange is that this line : `Class<?> cls = cl.loadClass("userDefineKeywords");` is not using the package and also that it is not starting in capital letters (the second thing is irrelevant but bothers me :) )